# Orthonormal base for $V$ of eigenvectors of $f$ given a scalar product

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

I had an exercise that gave me $f:V \to V$ and a scalar product $\Phi$.

$f$ was symmetric in $\Phi$ [that is $\forall v,w\in V$, $\Phi(f(v),w)=\Phi(v,f(w))]$

The spectral theorem tells me that I can find an orthonormal base for $V$ of eigenvectors. 
Another previous theorem tells simply that different eigenspaces are mutually orthogonal.

But, orthogonal for which scalar product??

The eigenvectors I found in that exercise were orthogonal for both the canonical product and $\Phi$. Was it luck?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear: why do you suppose there are two scalar products?  What is the scalar product other than $\Phi$?

Comment: @Mnifldz the usual inner product

Comment: @user3621272 are we to assume that $V$ is an inner product space (that is, that there exists a canonical inner product)?

Comment: You're right about my question, sorry; I don't know how to explain. Actually, the canonical product (of $\mathbb{R}^n$) is not mentioned in the exercise so let's forget about it. I only know there is $V$ with $\Phi$. But two vectors can be orthogonal for a product and not orthogonal for another one. Right? If the product considered in the exercise was different, was it possible that the eigenvectors weren't orthogonal?

Comment: OOh, maybe the eigenvectors are for sure orthogonal in $\Phi$ because $f$ is symmetric in $\Phi$??

Comment: @user3621272 that last comment is correct.

Comment: @user3621272 and yes, two vectors that are orthogonal with respect to one product might not be with respect to another.